# Form size parameters changed when transferring project

Tags: c#

Does anyone know why does the form size parameters change when I transfer my C# project from one computer to another? For example, when I was working at school on my laptop, I set the form size to 1000;700 and now, on my home computer it's 887;562. Why does this happen?

Comment: Is it scaling according to your display resolution? I.e. is the resolution on the school and home machines different?

Comment: What kind of application (WinForms, WPF, something else)?  Where do you set the size, and what units do you set it to?

Comment: Yes, the resolution on my home/school computer is different and I did not change the default units so, I guess that's pixels. I'm working on a windows forms app.

Comment: Could be scaling based on current monitor's dpi settings. Also, there seems to be a long standing bug/feature/limitation in visual studio's Winforms designer that the Form size cannot be bigger than the current display's resolution (i.e. 800x600, 1280x720, 1920x1080)

Comment: Indeed, but why would that affect the "size numbers" that are displayed on different resolutions?